# Linear interpolation how to insert points in a feature matrix in order to make them of equal size

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, linear-interpolation

In a lip reading project. I have a data set of not equal number of frames for each video a feature matrix was extracted where the number of rows is the number of frames and the columns is the value of the feature extracted.
The problem is that the videos are not of equal number of frames. I need to make them equal using linear interpolation and adding the missing point.

Comment: What is your input? A nxmx3xf matrix where nxm is the pixel size, 3 the number of colour channels and f the number of frames? Have you tried using `interpn`?

Comment: my input is a n*m matrix where n is the number of frames and m is the angles between the lip points. i tried to use interp1q  however i dont get the last parameter what is it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
newframes=11 %number of frames you want
interpolate_data=interpn(1:size(Data,1),1:size(Data,2),Data,linspace(1,size(Data,1),newframes),1:size(Data,2))
```

For the second dimensions, indices are untouched to have no interpolation. For the first dimension linspace is used to define a interpolation grid with `newframes` values.